# UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 1973: character maps to <undefined> but Only With MP3 Files

Tags: python, tkinter

The error above appear but only with MP3 Files and not when I open a python File instead

```
 from pygame import mixer 

 mixer.init() 


 mp3button = Button(master, text="Choose MP3", highlightthickness=0,bd=0, bg='black
',activebackground="black",fg="white",  command = lambda : see_check())




  checkvar = IntVar()
    checkplay = Checkbutton(master, text="Play MP3?",variable=checkvar ,onvalue=1 ,offvalue=0 ,font=('Arial',12), bg='blue', fg='white', activebackground='blue', activeforeground='white')



  def see_check(): 
        if checkvar.get() == 1: 
           
                file = askopenfile(mode='r',filetypes= [('MP3 Files', '*.mp3')])
                if file is not None: 
                    content = file.read()
                    mixer.music.load(content)
                    mixer.music.play()
```

How I get rid of this ? Thanks in advance :)

EDIT : Not working with mixer the sound does not play

EDIT 2 : It just display x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00$\x05\xc0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x11\x83B\xb6\x10\xe0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xfb\x10D\x00\x0f\xf0\x00\x00i\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x0f\xf0\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x01\xfe\x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00?\xc0\x00\x00\x04\xff\xff\xfa\x98\x95\xa8\x9f\xff\xfc\xeb\x1cD\xfcn<\x18t\x and more even if I want to play the content not printing it

Comment: Non-text files should be opened in binary mode `rb`.  Text files can be decoded, but even then you need to know what encoding to use.  The default (found with `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)`) is not necessarily correct.  But everything can be read in binary mode since no decoding occurs.

Comment: What sort of useful information do you expect to get from printing the contents of a mp4 file?

Comment: My bad I forgot to remove the print because I tested it with python files

Comment: It was MP3 idk why I said MP4

Comment: But still doesn't work even if i'm not doing something useless as just "printing the content" Idk why maybe the mode ? But you said that Non-text files should be opened in binary mode rb.

Comment: You need to pass the filename or `file` object instead of its content to `mixer.music.load()`. Study `pygame` document.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the filename or the open file object (`file` for your case) instead of the content of the file.

Also I would suggest to use `askopenfilename()` instead of `askopenfile()`:

```py
def see_check():
    if checkvar.get() == 1:
        # use askopenfilename() instead
        filename = askopenfilename(filetypes= [('MP3 Files', '*.mp3')])
        if filename is not None:
            # pass the selected filename to mixer.music.load()
            mixer.music.load(filename)
            mixer.music.play()
```

Comment: got this :  pygame.error: Failed loading libmpg123-0.dll: The specified module could not be found.

Comment: @Wawayayayayaya Try to reinstall `pygame`.  The mentioned DLL should be included in `pygame` module.  It works fine in my Windows 7 with Python 3.8.13 and pygame 2.1.2.

Comment: Ok I'll send you a feedback if it works

Comment: Tried this pip uninstall pygame then pip install pygame and still doesn't work.

Comment: Then I don't know why.  Make sure you use the same Python environment that you run the `pip install pygame` to run your code.

Comment: you mean pip or pygame ? pygame is 2.1.2 and pip 22.2.2 and python 3.10

Comment: I mean that you need to use *the same Python environment* that you use to install `pygame`.  Did you get any errors when you run `python -m pygame.tests mixer_music`? If not, then the `pygame` module should be installed properly.

Comment: pygame.mixer.music.queue(filename)
pygame.error: Failed loading libvorbisfile-3.dll: The specified module could not be found.

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 19 tests in 1.561s

FAILED (errors=10)

Comment: It may be caused by some dependent DLLs (other than those bundled by `pygame`) that your Windows does not have.  I cannot help anymore.